# How can I return or log all "name" values in this array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have this array of objects. Im trying to get the "name" property to return or console log

I've tried using indexes(probably wrong) so Im pretty stuck.

```
var peopleArray = [{
        name: "Harrison Ford",
        occupation: "Actor"
    },
    {
        name: "Justin Bieber",
        occupation: "Singer"
    },
    {
        name: "Vladimir Putin",
        occupation: "Politician"
    },
    {
        name: "Oprah",
        occupation: "Entertainer"
    }
]
```

Result should be:

```
["Harrison Ford", "Justin Bieber", "Vladimir Putin", "Oprah"]
```

Comment: `I've tried` nothing according to the "code" you posted

Comment: What did you try? I don't see any attempts posted

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```js
var peopleArray = [{name:"Harrison Ford",occupation:"Actor"},{name:"Justin Bieber",occupation:"Singer"},{name:"Vladimir Putin",occupation:"Politician"},{name:"Oprah",occupation:"Entertainer"}];
const res = peopleArray.map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var peopleArray = [{name:"Harrison Ford",occupation:"Actor"},{name:"Justin Bieber",occupation:"Singer"},{name:"Vladimir Putin",occupation:"Politician"},{name:"Oprah",occupation:"Entertainer"}];
var res = peopleArray.map(function(e) {
  return e.name;
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

To select property of array object, you can use `map()` function

```
let result = peopleArray.map(function(item) { return item['name']; });
```

If you want to select many properties from array object, you can use map and [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```
result = peopleArray.map(({ name, age }) => ({
  name, 
  age
}));
```

```js
var peopleArray = [{
        name: "Harrison Ford",
        occupation: "Actor",
        age: 21
    },
    {
        name: "Justin Bieber",
        occupation: "Singer",
        age: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Vladimir Putin",
        occupation: "Politician",
        age: 23
    },
    {
        name: "Oprah",
        occupation: "Entertainer",
        age: 24
    }
]

let result = peopleArray.map(function(item) { return item['name']; });
console.log(result);

result = peopleArray.map(({ name, age }) => ({
  name, 
  age
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a map

```
var person = peopleArray.map(({name}) => name);
console.log(person)
//["Harrison Ford", "Justin Bieber", "Vladimir Putin", "Oprah"]
```

You can use a forEach to display them one after the other

```
peopleArray.forEach(person => {
 console.log(person.name)
})
// "Harrison Ford"
// "Justin Bieber"
// "Vladimir Putin"
// "Oprah"
```